# Visual Studio 2012 RC designer does not recognize xaml for a Windows Metro app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed the release candidate for Visual Studio 2012 and the release preview for Windows 8.  I lost xaml intellisense and VS treats xaml as an XML document. Does anybody else have any ideas where to start to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply re-installed Visual Studio 2012 RC. I'm not willing to attempt to reproduce the problem, but I believe this is what I did: Upgrade windows 7 professional with Visual Studio 2010 installed to Windows 8 professional, Installed Visual Studio 2012 RC, Installed Windows 8 SDK.

My symptoms include:

1. Under tools, options, text editor, no xaml option.
2. When I tried to view a xaml page via designer, the property window displayed everything as an XML document
3. I could not view the designer in Visual Studio (I could in Blend), it would not let me and would show the xaml mark-up instead.
4. No intellisense.

Re-installing didn't take too much time, maybe 20-30 minutes.

Comment: same thing here. no xaml editor. btw, on all my other PCs, this editor crashes 50% of the time....

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on a XAML file in the Solution Explorer then choosing "Open with". In there choose "XAML UI Designer", hit "Set as Default" then hit "Ok". This should force VS to use the XAML Designer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that option, "XAML UI Designer".

Comment: I've set mine up to use XAML UI Designer but I still don't get any intellisense