# Visual Studio 2012 WPF Designer don't show. It show only the xaml source

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2010 then i upgraded to Visual Studio 2012.

When i open a .xaml file i can see only the xaml source and not the visual designer. With the 2010 version all works good.

I tried reinstalling and doing a reset of settings from command line but nothing changes. I have no errors. If i click on "Show projection window" it open again the xaml source and not the visual designer.

Why i can't see the visual designer? My PC is a HP 655 Notebook with 4GB RAM and ATI HD Raedon 7600 graphics card.

Thank you in advance.
Mauro

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm coming to this quite late, but one thing I found was going to:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Miscellaneous

Then see if "Always open documents in full XAML view" is checked. If so, uncheck it. (VS2010)

Comment: I solved reinstalling from the ISO image. Using the Web installer caused the problem. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had something like that, too, when I tried to 'reproduce' your situation by dragging the splitbar between designer and xaml all the way up. It disappeared and I couldn't get the desigener back by neither resetting the window layout nor by restarting VS. But my problem was solved simply by chosing `View-Designer` or Shift-F7. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the reply but when i press Shift + F7 it open me another xaml source editor. I don't know what is happening. It is like it don't recognize the XAML file correcly

Comment: Just found this in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595434/visual-studio-2012-not-recognizing-xaml-files-design-view-broken) :  `4. Try running devenv /Resetuserdata in Command Prompt to reset all of your VS environment and customization settings.`

Comment: I'm sorry but in my post i said "I tried reinstalling and doing reset of settings from command line ". I have already found the post you said but hadn't worked. :(

Comment: If this can help i resolved the problem. I have installed it with the web installer. So i removed it completly and downloaded and installed the offline ISO. Now I see the visual designer.