# C# WPF Build errror: CS0234 The type or namespace name * does not exist in the namespace *

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

For a few days now I've been researching about this error, but I haven't found a solution yet.

In my project 'Arcanium', this error is thrown:

> The type or namespace name 'GameWindow' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Arcanium.Arcanium.ClientSide' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

[Edit] The error is thrown at line 8 of GameWindow.xaml

Here are the classes:
GameWindow.xaml (Arcanium.Clientside):

```
<Window x:Name="Arcanium" x:Class="Arcanium.ClientSide.GameWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Arcanium.ClientSide"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Arcanium" Height="512" Width="512" Activated="OnActivated" Closing="OnClosing" KeyDown="OnKeyDown" KeyUp="OnKeyUp" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

GameWindow.xaml.cs (Arcanium.ClientSide):

```
using Arcanium.ClientSide.Engine;
using Arcanium.Engine.Graphics;
using Arcanium.Engine.User;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Arcanium.ClientSide {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for GameWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class GameWindow : Window {


public static int SizeX { get; private set; }
public static int SizeY { get; private set; }

private static GameWindow _window;

public GameWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    _window = this;
}

public static void DrawFrame(FastBitmap frame) {
    _window.Background = new ImageBrush(ImageSourceForBitmap(frame.GetBitmap()));
    frame.Dispose();
}

private static ImageSource ImageSourceForBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
    try {
        return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    } finally { NativeMethods.DeleteObject(handle); }
}

private void OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SizeX = 512;
    SizeY = 512;

    Game.ActivateGameLoop();
}

private void OnClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    Game.Running = false;
}

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    Input.HandleKeyboardPress(e.Key);
}

private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    Input.HandleKeyboardRelease(e.Key);
}

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}


}
}
```

(I cant figure out the correct formatting, this is my first time asking here)

I've already tried a couple of things.

1. What seems strange is that the compiler searches for GameWindow in the namespace 'Arcanium.Arcanium.Clientslide' and my class is in 'Arcanium.ClientSide'. In order to prevent this, I've tried removing Arcanium from the class path (GameWindow.xaml, line 1), which causes it to not find the methods for events (registered in GameWindow.xaml, line 8), and not knowing the InitializeComponent() method anymore, which led to my conclusion GameWindow.xaml.cs couldn't be inherited properly anymore.
2. I've tried restarting Visual Studio and my whole computer
3. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project
4. Ive tried changing the target platform from x64 to x32 and back (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216096/wpf-the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace))
5. [Edit] I've tried deleting the Window (both classes) and re-adding them. As soon as I registered the events, the error came back.

This error only occurs when I try to build the project. Visual Studio doesn't mark it in the text editor.

When I try to change the x:Class path in the Xaml to 'GameWindow', as Bijan requested, it seems to find the class, but not the methods in it and it marks InitializeComponent() as non-existent.

Any tips?

Comment: What if recreate a new XAML file from scratch?

Comment: Sorry I haven't listed that. Already tried a couple of times. As soon as I add back the event registrations, the error is back again. I'll write it into my question

Comment: Your xaml and cs files work fine in an empty project. You will need to look for other things. Is the error shown pointing to your xaml file?

Comment: Yes, line 8, where the events are at.

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio?

Comment: 2017. It says so in the tags

Comment: Or 15.5.2 if you mean that

Comment: Yes. Ok. I had same issue when I was on 15.5.0. After update to 15.5.2 this problem disappeared. Also, before the update I tried to change solution configuration from Release to Debug and vice versa. It did not work until I updated VS.

Comment: I hope I don't have to wait until the next update D:

Comment: it should be `x:Class="GameWindow"` in the first line

Comment: Now the same happens as if I were to remove one 'Arcanium' from the x:Class path :/