# WPF XAML - Invalid Markup but still compiles without issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have a WPF application and my XAML says "Invalid Markup" but the program still compiles with no issues. I want this fixed because it makes it very difficult to design UI without any actual UI to look at while I'm writing XAML. Is there a fix for this? I'm using VS Pro 2019

**The Error**

```
XDG0008 The name "IntToImageConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SDB". Line 14
```

I have done some research and have tried:

- Cleaning and re-building the solutions
- Switching between Debug and Release configs
- Switching between x64 and x86, and Any
- The answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216096/wpf-the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)
- Restarting VS
- Creating a symbolic link (My code resides on a network share)
- Ignoring the issue and designing in Blend
- Adding `;assembly=MyAssembly`

No matter what I do, it says "Invalid Markup". I cannot copy the project to my desktop to develop since my desktop is running Deep Freeze.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
1    <Window
2        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
3        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
4        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="SDB.MainWindow"
5        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDB"
6        Title="Application Test"
7        Width="1920"
8        WindowState="Maximized"
9        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
10       Loaded="Window_Loaded"
11       Icon="/Resources/icon_database2.png" Height="1145"
12       VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
13   <Window.Resources>
14       <local:IntToImageConverter x:Key="IntToImageConverter" />
15   </Window.Resources>
```

**IntToImageConverter.cs**

```
namespace SDB {

    public class IntToImageConverter {


    }
}
```

Comment: When you say your code resides on a network share. You mean you're editing code isn't on your local machine's C drive? You can expect no end of weird problems if the code you're not working with in visual studio is on some other remote computer.

Comment: @Andy That's correct. But it's unrealistic for me to copy the code to my local machine every day

Comment: Been a while since I tried it, but in my experience it's simply not viable developing against source which is purely on a server. You could automate copying the sln every day from a repository. No Git? You can't copy the solution to a usb and work on that? Could you put visual studio on a server and remote onto that? If none of the above then I suggest you find someone who'll change one of those stoppers and let you develop.

Comment: Try unloading the project, delete the bin and obj directories, reload the project and building